# Replace a string with a line feed in SAS

Tags: regex, sas, datastep

I want to read a file and find the word “the” and introduce a line feed. i.e. find and replace the text `‘the’` to `‘/nthe’`  Can you please help?

```
    /*input.txt*/
    Many a slip between the cup and the lip. 

    /*Required output*/
    Many a slip between 
    the cup and 
    the lip. 

    /*sas datastep*/
    data inp;
    infile "c:/tmp/input.txt";
    /*ADD LOGIC*/
    infile "c:/tmp/output.txt";
    run;
```

Comment: several options, one would be http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000215027.htm

Comment: Transwd is creating the text as '/n' instead of creating a line feed.         test_txt = tranwrd(text, "the", "/nthe");

Comment: linefeed is interpreted as '0A'x in sas, so try  test_txt =tranwrd(text,"the",cat('0A'x,"the")); (cr is '0d'x if you also want to add it)

Comment: Works fine, Thanks @kl78.

Comment: @kl78 Please enter those into an answer so the OP can accept it and effectively close this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Already answered in comments, summarized as answer*

There are several options to do a find and replace in SAS, I would suggest using [tranwrd](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000215027.htm).

SAS interprets a linefeed as '0A'x.
For a carriage return you would use '0D'x.

So the solution for you would be :

```
 test_txt =tranwrd(text,"the",cat('0A'x,"the"));
```